# How to create angle gradient within a certain angular range?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

The angle gradient tool in Photoshop produces a 360° gradient. How can I produce an angle gradient that shows only a certain portion of this effect, such as 90° or 180°?

Comment: Would a 180 degree gradient not just be a linear gradient?

Comment: Meant was the range. I want to create only a quarter or a half of a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **Layer Style** where you have complete control over the angle....

[image]

Or maybe a Layer Style combined with a mask??

[image]

I'm not totally clear on what it is you are asking.

This maybe?? Draw the shape first, then apply the **Gradient Overlay Layer Style** and while the *Layer Style Dialog window is open* you can click-drag in the image to reposition the gradient.

[image]

Using an angled gradient in a layer style this way allows you to adjust the angle for different variations, like in a clock, if you wanted a gradient moving up to 10pm, then away.. you can do it this way. I probably should have shown that more clearly in the animation.

Otherwise, you could just use a centered radial gradient either with a mask or as a layer style.

Comment: Thank you! Imagine a round station clock where I want to add a angle gradient from 9 to 12. It should not overlap.

Comment: @Ben You'd have to use the Layer Style + a mask or draw the shape you want, then add the layer style. See the animation I added to this answer.

Comment: That's great! Could you explain me how to create the quarter layer mask?

Comment: I just drew a circle then altered 2 sides of it. There's no mask in the animation.

Comment: It's a shape, where Scott applied a layer style. It's not a mask. Well it kind of is, but it's not referred to as a mask..

Answer (score -1):

If I  understand correctly, all you have to do is to type in, the actual degree, "I. E., 80" in the box to the right of the angle box.

Does this make sense?

Comment: There's no such box I'm aware of, could you post a screenshot?